# Dynamically generate sitemap page for a React Single page application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, single-page-application, sitemap

It's unclear to me how I should go about this.
I want a page on the website to have all links in the entire website in a tree like structure.
How can I approach this problem?

Comment: do you have json or arrray  where your data is stored

Comment: You must have a router or something like that for handling your app routing. You can design a data model for the structure and create a component is able to consume the data and render a sitemap

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-router-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap) package.

as the documentation explains:

> After running the script, a sitemap.xml file will be created, which includes all paths, described in the configuration of react-router

Comment: i think it's not working properly with react router dom v6.